# Field Calculator Odd IF Statement?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, python-parser, if-else, field-calculator

I am working on a street addressing project.
I want to add a number to every odd number.
Example if [field] is odd [field]+=1.
How can I do this in ArcMap using the field calculator.

I used to work programming in Microsoft Visual Basic And C++.But how can i do this in Arc Map field calculator.

[image]

What is wrong in this expression.

I used the expression that Ali Put.
But still I am Having errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select using Mod(fld,2)=0

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the field expression. You had that part right in the first image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The modulo operation in Python is carried out using the % operator i.e.

```
>>> print 3 % 2
1
```

Incorporating this into your function:

```
def calc(val):
    if val % 2 > 0:
        return val + 1
    else:
        return val
```

Then underneath the codeblock, in the field expression:

```
calc(!LR!)
```

The field calculator will take the value from the LR field and push it into the calc function. If it is odd, the value will be incremented by 1 and returned, otherwise the input value will be returned without modification.

Comment: Val + (Val ℅ 2) will do